# Add new object into existing json

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I have `dropdown` like this.

```
<input id="tripFrom" type="text" 
   angular-select2="{type:'typeahead',placeholder:'- Select -'}" 
   select-typeahead-params="{removeTripId:currentTrip.customerDetails.tripToID, type:'startsFrom'}" 
   select-typeahead-url="getTripFrom('startsFrom')"
   ng-model="currentTrip.fromTripID" 
   select-text="currentTrip.startingAreaName" 
/>
```

For this `dropdown` I am getting data like this:

```
{"success":true,
 "items":[
   {"id":56565,"text":"andra"},
   {"id":56568,"text":"tamilnadu"}
 ]
}
```

My question is when I add some new text in `dropdown` (which is not present in `dropdown`)I need to create its as new `object` inside of `items`.

When I `blur` the `dropdown` new added data should be displayed in that `dropdown` as selected.

This what I have added:

```
$('#s2id_autogen8_search').change(function(){
  var data=[];var items={};
  var newAddress=$('#s2id_autogen8_search').val();
  var newId=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000+1);
  var newTripAddress={id:newId,text:newAddress}
  items.id=newId;
  items.text=newAddress;
 data.push(items)
  /*$("#tripFrom").select2({
    data : newTripAddress})*/
});
```

But my input is not displaying when I `blur` it. What I did wrong?

Comment: What does `items` refers to?

Comment: please check my json

Comment: None of your code shows your element using `items`, eg there is no data binding for it that I can see. How is changing it supposed to change your element?

Comment: No its a json name getting from server side.I dont now whether its correct or not. thats why am asking you guys.

Comment: guys I have added into array but when i focusout its not displaying thats only problem now .please check updated code.Its addded as new array why am unable to add in existing array

Comment: Have you tried run $scope.$apply after adding the item to the list?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the blur instead of the change event.

```
$('#s2id_autogen8_search').change(function(){

// use this instead 

$('#s2id_autogen8_search').on('blur', function(){
```

It might be as simple as that.